# Wordpress theme style colour changes

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Thanks in advance for any help given :)

Im fairly new to web design and am still learning php and css on the fly but can read and understand the code due to previous experience.

http://wilbyrne.com/esa/

Thats the address for the website im currently looking at.. im aware its very messy and untidy but im mainly looking to change the grey colour of the 4 teaser boxes underneath the slider on the main page.

[image]

the box that is blue is being hovered over and im looking to change each box colour independantly of the style..

im not too sure what is needed for any advice or help on this..

so any code requests i will gladly post :)

Thanks in advance..

BenJi

Comment: Are you the owner of that website?

Comment: Give each box a class, and then change the `overlay` background-color property.

Comment: yes i am the owner of the domain so i have full access to it but i work for a graphics company that is redesigning the website.. but it is a test site.. but my question is still valid becease im using the exact same theme and problem on a different site also.. @DaanHeskes

Comment: and thanks nick thats exactly what i was trying to do but the code seems impossible to find.. wat can i link in here so u can have a look ? if you would like @Nick R

Comment: Well, there seems to be a class `img_grayscale` in the CSS. You might want to look at that/change it or remove the class of the image.

Comment: Well you currently have `.widget_out_stuff2 .item-con-t1 header .overlay { background-color:#0F9DE0 }` on line `167`. What you need to do is add a class to `theme-one-fourth`, so you can differentiate the 4 boxes. And then do something like `.box1 header .overlay { background-color: your-colour; }`

Comment: Unfortunatly @DaanHeskes i tried that too and the grayscale class seems to be on top of the style colour so when you get rid of it it just shows the styles colour and doesnt let u change each individually.. or if it does i cant find where.. the theme seems to be really annoying

Comment: Thanks @NickR that sound like it will work.. im a complete noob though and cant seem to find where that snippet of code is :(

Comment: If you view the source of the page, you should see that CSS, starting from `<style type="text/css" id="dynamic-styles">`

Comment: ah ok cool thanks @NickR found it but i still cant find it in the backend im looking in the themes main.css file is that correct ?

Comment: It looks like it's just being injected into the page, and doesn't exist it a .css file, so I'm not sure exactly where it would be coming from. It might be worth doing a `find in files` search with a text editor for `dynamic-styles`

Comment: cool il give that a try now thanks for all your help :) al post back again after i have a look :)

Comment: This question belongs to another site in the Stack Exchange network http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh im very sorry about that didnt know there was a wordpress section.. Im used to posting here jus from when i used to ask and answer android/ java questions

Comment: Sorry @NickR for the delayed reply.. but i cannot find it anywhere.. ive literally searched everywhere now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your looking for `.overlay .tran03slinear` classes they seem to be included in your main index so im guessing as its wordpress there is a function that hooks into `wp_head` with the css possibly look in you themes function file also in any head files for a  block either inside a php function with `add_action('wp_head','the_function_name');` if its in the head it could just be wrapped in the `<style>` markup. alternatively you could just override the css by re declaring .overlay>.tran03slinear in you css files so ts outputted last that way it will override what is already there